# Spring flyway Rebase migration scripts

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, migration, flyway, rebase

Hi in my project I have around 200 flyway migration scripts and I need to clean those and create a new baseline. For example, I have the following schema versions

```
V1_0_0__baseline.sql
V1_1_0__schema-change1.sql
V1_2_0__schema-change2.sql
.
.
.
V1_200_0__schema-change200.sql
```

Now I need to clean the **src/main/resources/db/migration** files and create a new record as below.

```
V2_0_0__baseline.sql
```

Then I added this config and try to rebase the schema versions

```
spring.flyway.baselineOnMigrate = true
spring.flyway.baseline-version=2
```

flyway core version: **8.5.13**

spring boot version: **2.7.7**

Are there any configs missing here? I needed a solution that didn't involve many manual steps.

Comment: Rebase with what?